# Label containing siunitx syntax below an arrow in chemformula gives an error

Tags: arrows, siunitx, labels, chemmacros, chemformula

When using the following code everything works just fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[modules=all]{chemmacros}

\begin{document}
  \ch{!(colorless)( VO3- ) ->[\SI{-0.255}{V}][ Fe^2+ ] !(blue)( VO^2+ )}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But I need to switch the places between potential and reducing agent:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[modules=all]{chemmacros}

\begin{document}
  \ch{!(colorless)( VO3- ) ->[ Fe^2+ ][\SI{-0.255}{V}] !(blue)( VO^2+ )}
\end{document}
```

Compilation fails with the following error: `Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. ... Fe^2+ ][\SI{-0.255}{V}] !(blue)( VO^2+ )}`. What is going on here and how can I use `siunitx` syntax properly in a label *below* arrow?

Comment: The problem does not just appear to be using `\SI` below the line, but (maybe also) in using `Fe^2+` above the line.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Yep, but why? Without `[\SI{-0.255}{V}]` everything is fine. I flipped through `chemformula` docs and it seems like the syntax I'm using is correct. Also, `mhchem` with `\underset{...}{...}` instead of `!(...)(...)` works just fine and has no issues with `\SI{...}{...}` passed as the secondary option...

Comment: write `->[ Fe^2+ ][ "\SI{-0.255}{V}" ]`

Comment: @clemens maybe I'm out of date on packages, but the above-arrow quantity still blows me up.  To get it to work, I have to use `->[$\textrm{Fe}^{2+}$][ "\SI{-0.255}{V}" ]`

Comment: @clemens Thank you, that did it! Though I don't understand the magic behind it as your manual for `chemformula` on p. 24 uses `\ch{A ->[\SI{100}{\celsius}] B}` as an example without extra space and "...", and it works fine. Maybe you could provide an answer with an explanation at some point (no rush, as long as it works, it's fine)?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes did you leave the spaces around `Fe^2+`? They're important!

Comment: I did, but forgot to leave spaces around the `"` (didn't realize the importance).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is quite obvious once you know it. Remember that `chemformula` splits its input at *every* space! Let's have a look at the different inputs and what `chemformula` sees:

In the case `->[\SI{-0.255}{V}][ Fe^2+ ]` `chemformula` parses three parts:

1. `->[\SI{-0.255}{V}][` – this is detected as an **arrow** which means that apart from replacing `->` with an arrow command everything is left as is
2. `Fe^2+` – this is detected as a **chemical formula** and treated as such
3. `]` – this is detected as a **chemical formula** and treated as such

In the case `->[ Fe^2+ ][\SI{-0.255}{V}]` `chemformula` parses three parts:

1. `->[` – this is detected as an **arrow**
2. `Fe^2+` – this is detected as a **chemical formula**
3. `][\SI{-0.255}{V}]` – this is detected as a **chemical formula** and treated as such; *this means for example that numbers get converted to sub- and superscripts according to the rules explained in the manual*! As a consequence `\SI` cannot parse its argument any more!

In the case `->[ Fe^2+ ][ "\SI{-0.255}{V}" ]` `chemformula` parses five parts:

1. `->[` – this is detected as an **arrow**
2. `Fe^2+` – this is detected as a **chemical formula**
3. `][` – this is detected as a **chemical formula**
4. `"\SI{-0.255}{V}"` – this is detected as **escaped text**; the `"` are stripped and the rest is left as is
5. `]` – this is detected as a **chemical formula**

There is one basic rule: a part that can not cleanly be detected as special input (text, stoichiometric factor, arrow, …) is always treated as a chemical formula.