# Error when compiling pdf - problem with chemmacros

Tags: packages, chemmacros

It appears that chemmacros is uninstalled or something strange. When run this **minimal example**:

```
   \documentclass[12pt,twoside
]{report}
\usepackage[headheight=18pt,a4paper, width=150mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm, bindingoffset=6mm, headsep=18pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish,es-noquoting]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage[hypcap=false]{caption}
\usepackage[activate={true,nocompatibility},final,tracking=true,kerning=true,spacing=true,factor=1100,stretch=10,shrink=10]{microtype}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{
  formula = chemformula ,
  modules = all
}


\begin{document}
\begin{reactions}
A &<=> B\label{reaccio6} \\
C &<=> D \label{reaccionRef5}\\
A + C &<=> B + D  \label{reaccion_neta5}
\end{reactions}
donde la \ref{reaccio6} tiene asociado $\Delta G^\circ_{\textrm{desc}}$, \ref{reaccionRef5} $\Delta G^\circ_{\textrm{ref}}$
y la reacción neta, $\Delta G^\circ_{\textrm{neto}}$. El valor de la energía libre de referencia puede ser experimental o estimado.
\end{document}
```

Latex reports the **error**:

```
 ! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> r@reaccio\chemformula
_subscript:n {6}
l.31 ...cript:n {6}}{{1}{1}{}{equation.R.0.0.1}{}}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

The document has `chemmacros` uploaded in preamble. 
My Linux system is Debian.

Any help?

Comment: have you loaded the reactions module, like it says in the error message?

Comment: But isn't the module automatically loaded if I load `chemmacros` as `\usepackage{chemmacros}`?@DavidCarlisle

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it returns the same for a chemmacros module called `newman`

Comment: Try `\chemsetup{modules = all}`

Comment: presumably not, given that the error message defined by that package says to load an extra chemmacros module:-)

Comment: @koleygr Thanks for the comment. Still lot of errors..

Comment: @HernanMiraola may be the new errors are not related with missing modules. I suggest to give a code that we can test.

Comment: I have never used the package but the error you post says "See the chemmacros documentation for further information." and `texdoc chemmacros` suggests the simplest thing is `\chemsetup{modules=all}` as suggested by @koleygr

Comment: the code you posted doesn't use `\chemsetup` at all.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I had put the sentence below 'Also tried \chemsetup{modules=all} but same errors.'..

Comment: @clemens hmm..I don't understand. The problem  -as I see it- is that the document doesn't compile. And for some strange reason it is related to `chemmacros`. Anything you think I need to change in the post just tell me..I am trying to be honest, really.

Comment: As far as i can remember, you are using version 4 of chemmacros and underscores are not allowed in chem labels.

Comment: @Johannes_B hi, what a memory(version was 4.6, I believe). No, I have installed the last version of Latex to avoid some troubles. Now it is 2017 version and 5.8b or something like that in `chemmacros`. Thanks for the comment. I really don't have idea about how to fix it.

Comment: @HernanMiraola the error you are now having is a different error which stems from wrong usage of the package… it is not the same error that you reported yesterday and it has another cause! New problems should be posted as new questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the manual of `chemmacros` shows on page 44 you should enclose `\label{...}` with `"..."`.

[image]

The problem behind this has been discussed a few times on this site already, the last time here: [Label containing siunitx syntax below an arrow in chemformula gives an error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/392687/)

`chemmacros` also provides macros for Gibbs enthalpy and the lot…

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}

\usepackage[spanish,es-noquoting]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 

\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{
  formula = chemformula ,
  modules = all
}

\begin{document}

\begin{reactions}
A &<=> B "\label{reaccio6}" \\
C &<=> D "\label{reaccionRef5}" \\
A + C &<=> B + D "\label{reaccion_neta5}"
\end{reactions}

donde la \ref{reaccio6} tiene asociado \gibbs*[subscript-right=desc]{},
\ref{reaccionRef5} \gibbs*[subscript-right=ref]{} y la reacción neta,
\gibbs*[subscript-right=neto]{}. El valor de la energía libre de referencia
puede ser experimental o estimado.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It worked perfectly.