# Reaction annotation with math using chemformula and chemmacros packages

Tags: chemmacros, chemformula

In the following MWE, I attempt to use the [`chemformula`](https://ctan.org/pkg/chemformula) and [`chemmacros`](https://ctan.org/pkg/chemmacros?lang=en) packages to typeset a reaction annotated with some math. Why does Reaction 1 compile but Reaction 2 does not?

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}

\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage[
  expansion = false ,
  tracking = smallcaps ,
  letterspace = 40 ,
  final
]{microtype}
\usepackage[font={sf,small},labelsep=quad,labelfont=sc]{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usechemmodule{reactions}
\chemsetup[reactions]{
  before-tag = R,
  tag-open = [,
  tag-close = ]
}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

% Reaction 1
\begin{reactions}
  2 H2O + 2 e- &<=> H2 + 2 OH-&{$E^{\circ}$}
\end{reactions}

% Reaction 2
\begin{reactions}
  2 H2O + 2 e- &<=> H2 + 2 OH-&{$E^{\circ} \approx \SI{-0.83}{\volt}$}
\end{reactions}

\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Answer (score 2):

Removing the space between `E^{\circ}` and `\approx` is sufficient to make the code compilable.

For an in-depth explanation on the role of spaces inside of `chemformula`'s `\ch`, which is what the `reaction` environment's body is parsed with unless instructed otherwise, take a look at [cgnieder's answer to a related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/392693/134144)

[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}

\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage[
  expansion = false ,
  tracking = smallcaps ,
  letterspace = 40 ,
  final
]{microtype}
\usepackage[font={sf,small},labelsep=quad,labelfont=sc]{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usechemmodule{reactions}
\chemsetup[reactions]{
  before-tag = R,
  tag-open = [,
  tag-close = ]
}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{reactions}
  2 H2O + 2 e- &<=> H2 + 2 OH-& $E^{\circ}\approx \SI{-0.83}{\volt}$
\end{reactions}

\end{document}
```

`chemmacros` by default loads the `chemformula` package in order to typeset chemical formulae but also offers the possibility to use other packages such as `mhchem` (`\chemsetup{formula= mhchem}`). Since `mhchem` uses a different parsing mechanism, the space inside the equation is not an issue:

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}

\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage[
  expansion = false ,
  tracking = smallcaps ,
  letterspace = 40 ,
  final
]{microtype}
\usepackage[font={sf,small},labelsep=quad,labelfont=sc]{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usechemmodule{reactions}
\chemsetup[reactions]{
  before-tag = R,
  tag-open = [,
  tag-close = ]
}
\chemsetup{formula= mhchem}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{reactions}
  2 H2O + 2 e- &<=> H2 + 2 OH-& $E^{\circ} \approx \SI{-0.83}{\volt}$
\end{reactions}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There is also math escaping (which inserts a small amount of space after the math per default, though). The _real_ problem is the space between `{\circ}` and  `\approx`. It is hidden in your solution by the outer pair of braces… Without it `"..." also fails unless the space is removed. See here for example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/392693/

Comment: @cgnieder: I've updated my answer accordingly.